# Update ProgressBar in Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, adapter

I want to show a progressBar when upload files to server. I can get progress values according to written bytes of file. But I can not update the progress bar. The problem; progress bar is filled to max immediately.

xml:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_file_uploading"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="1" />
```

In adapter I used a higher order function to get viewHolder. So in this way I can access the progress bar outside of Adapter and use it.

```
    var holderCallback: ((RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) -> Unit) = { }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FileViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position))
    holderCallback(holder)
    }
```

In fragment, I have progress values and these values are correct when I debugged.

```
val countingRequestBody = CountingRequestBody(it) { bytesWritten, contentLength ->
                val progress = 1.0 * bytesWritten / contentLength
                println("Written: $progress")//0.17,0.35,...1.0 (correct values)
                fileAdapter.holderCallback = { holder ->
                    (holder as FileListAdapter.FileViewHolder).progressBar.progress = progress.toInt()
                }
            }
```

So I think there might be a problem with the code in fragment to update progressBar in adapter. I'm not sure this is right way.

The design I want to achieve:

[image: this is the design]

Answer (score 2):

Your progress value is a number between 0 and 1. when you convert it to Int it returns 0 or 1. As you set the maximum value of the progress bar to 1 so progress bar is filled to max immediately.
I think you should change the current value like this:

```
 val progress = 100 * (bytesWritten / contentLength)
```

and also set the max value of the progress bar to 100.

```
 android:max="100"
```

Comment: thanks for answer @AlirezA Barakati. I changed the way to update progressBar and then applied your solution. It works but only for first item. When I add second file or multiple files the progressBar not updated correctly. I added it as another answer can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

Define android:max in xml as an integer, not value between 0 and 1. For example, if you set android:max to 100 and progressBar.progress to 25, then 1/4 of progress bar will be filled.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I applied that solution but it's working only first item.

Answer (score 1):

As I searched accessing the view outside of the adapter not recommended. So I changed the code and applied @AlirezA Barakati's solution.

In fragment:

```
val countingRequestBody = CountingRequestBody(it) { bytesWritten, contentLength ->
    val progress = 100 * bytesWritten / contentLength
    progressValues.add(progress.toInt()) //it's mutable list
    activity?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
        fileAdapter.setProgressValues(progressValuesDistinct)
    })
}
```

In Adapter added this function:

```
fun setProgressValues(progressValuesList: List<Int>) {
    progressValues.clear()
    progressValues.addAll(progressValuesList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    /* if(currentList.size > 1) {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    } else {
        notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
    }*/
}
```

In ViewHolder:

```
progressValues.forEach {
    progressFileUploading.progress = it
    if(it >= 100) {
        progressFileUploading.hide()
    }
}
```

So only the first item's progressBar is updated. Others are not updated. I didn't understand what could be wrong?

Comment: Please provide me with your adapter class. I think something is wrong with your codes.